# Как заполнить столбец по значениям, полученным после двойной группировки?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется исходный датафрейм над которым производится группировка по 2-м столбцам: дата и user_id для дальнейшего подсчёта суммы элементов в каждую дату для каждого юзера. Необходимо в исходный датафрейм добавить сумму для соответствующей пары дата-юзер, столбец **streak**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы попытались решить задачку?

Comment: Когда одна группировка, делаю с помощью map, но у него один вход один выход, всю голову сломал

Comment: Наверное нужно вставить значения в столбец по условию df.where.

Comment: Мне кажется нет, where даёт 2 выхода на одно условие, а здесь нужно бы map по 2-м условиям, но он так не работает

Comment: Пример данных и вашего кода должен быть в вопросе в воспроизводимом виде, а не скриншотом. пока голосую  за закрытие вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

```py
df_feed.set_index(['user_id', 'date']).join(streak_num, how = 'inner', rsuffix = '_cnt').reset_index()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]